# Why was the optional '=' added to the define directive of gnu make 4?

Tags: gnu-make

Looking at the Gnu make 4.2 manual for [Defining multi-line variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multi_002dLine.html#Multi_002dLine), we see an example:

```
define two-lines =
echo foo
echo $(bar)
endef
```

and the comment

> The define directive is followed on the same line by the name of the variable being defined and an (**optional**) assignment operator, and nothing more.

I have been tripped up on several occasions by including the optional `=`, and then having (often subtle) problems when building on a different machine using Gnu make 3.81. Of course, I should not be using 4.2 syntax when running 3.81! But I have found this an easy mistake to make, especially since neither the URL nor the content of [1](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multi_002dLine.html#Multi_002dLine) indicate what version is being documented (you have to click `Up` 2 levels to see the version).

So, back to my question: why was the optional `=` introduced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It allows you to create macros using all the different assignment operators.  In particular it allows you to use:

```
define foo :=
```

to get a simply-expanded variable, or

```
define foo ?=
```

to get an optionally-assigned variable, etc.  As part of this you are allowed to use the (redundant)

```
define foo =
```

as well.

Comment: Well that makes sense! Thanks @MadScientist. I assume this means that the behaviour in 3.81 is that all variables created with `define` are implicitly recursively expanded?